# Is it possible to have Vim open a file in its default (non-vim) editor?

Tags: vim, ctags

I have cTags set up to tag a bunch of custom stuff for simple internal scripting language I use at work. For various reasons, I'd like to have it set up so that if I `<C-]>` on certain tags vim opens them in their default editor rather than in another buffer. Is it possible to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function and autocommand will cause matching files to be loaded in the program associated with the file type, just like hitting `x` from a vim dir explorer buffer.

```
function s:OSOpen(fname, bufname)
  call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(a:fname,0)
  exec "bdel " . a:bufname
endfunction
" replace the file pattern with whatever you need
au BufEnter *.txt call s:OSOpen(expand("<afile>"), expand("<abuf>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mac, you can use the [`open`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command.